# Update scope inner object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a complex model to represent a simplified version of a football tournament, something like this:

```
var model = {
    groups: [
         {
             name: "group A",
             matchList: [
                 {id: "1", name: "Team 1 vs Team 2", score: "0-0"},
                 {id: "2", name: "Team 3 vs Team 4", score: "0-0"},
                 {id: "3", name: "Team 5 vs Team 6", score: "0-0"},
                 {id: "4", name: "Team 7 vs Team 8", score: "0-0"},
             ]
         },{
             name: "group B",
             matchList: [
                 ...
             ]
         },
         ... and so on ...
    ]
}
```

**For sake of simplicity** I'm showing, for the first group only, every match with its current result. Every match is clickable and opens a modal where the user can change the match result:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="match in matchList" ng-click="editMatchScore(match)">
        <td>{{match.name}}</td>
        <td>{{match.score}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

this table has, inside its controller, the following scope:

```
$scope.matchList = model.groups[0];

$scope.editMatchScore = function(selectedMatch){
    // Here, I open the modal where the user can change the match result.
}
```

Everything works fine, my modal returns a new object with the user-inputed match results, for example:

```
{newResult: "5-0"} //This object is successfully returned by the modal
```

Now I'd like to update the original model, in order to automatically update the view containing the group results as well.

How can I scan the current scope to find the correct match and update it?

This is what I've tried so far (using *lodash* to extract the object), this code is launched after the modal is closed and the newResult is returned:

```
var group = _.find($scope.groups, function(current){
    return current.name === "group A"; // get the first group
});
var match = _.find(group, function(current){
    return current.id === "1"; // Assume I'm editing the first match at the moment
});

match.score = "5-0";
```

I hoped that `match` would hold a reference to the match-inner-object of the original model, and therefore I hoped I could edit it and see the changes reflected to the original model, but unfortunately it is not working as expected. I'm probably missing something, anyone can help?

Hope I was clear enough, thanks

Comment: Are you using `angular-ui`'s `$modal`?

Comment: @NewDev yes, I followed this example: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular-UI's `$modal` provides `.result` - which is a promise of a result. So, since you have the reference to the originally selected "match" object, just modify it:

```
$scope.editMatchScore = function(selectedMatch){
    // Here, I open the modal where the user can change the match result.
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({...});

    modalInstance.result.then(function (newScore) {
      selectedMatch.score = newScore;
    });
}
```